# How to separate two elements that are stuck on each other only on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

[Here's how it looks on mobile devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp4q8.jpg)

[Here's how it looks on desktops and laptops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GO98.jpg)

I'm no expert but I've been tasked with doing this, this is based on a template that I found,there is some javascript included but I really don't know where to look when it comes to javascript.
I just want them to look separated, preferably one above the other,how can I do that through css and html?

CSS and HTML

```
  a.main-filled-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000dff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

}

a.main-filled-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000dff;
}

<div class="item">
            <div class="img-fill">
                <img src="assets/images/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text-content">
                  <h3>WELCOME TO AKSM</h3>
                  <h5>Leading surveying company</h5>
                  <a href="https://www.aksm.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/%CE%9CME_WEBENa-1.pdf" class="main-filled-button">EPAnEK 2014-2020</a>
                  <a href="https://www.aksm.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/aksm-prodiagrafes-popup.jpg" class="main-filled-button">ΠΡΟΔΙΑΓΡΑΦΕΣ</a>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add margin

```
 a.main-filled-button {
   margin: 10px 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query for mobile devices in the css file

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .main-filled-button {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use css flex-box layout, one approach is as below with explanatory comments in the code:

```css
/* simple CSS reset to have the browser use the same sizing calculations
   for all elements across all browsers, removing default margin and
   padding: */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* to add visibility, a page background of white is poor contrast
   against a white background for the <a> elements (adjust to taste): */
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* using flex-box layout: */
div.text-content {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  /* shorthand, setting:
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap; */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* specifying a 1em gap between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  /* setting the content vertically and horizontally centered,
     shorthand for:
       justify-content: center;
       align-content: center; */
  place-content: center;
}

h3,
h5 {
  /* forcing the <h3> and <h5> elements to take 100% of
     their parent element's width: */
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* setting the text-alignment to center: */
  text-align: center;
}

/* no changes below: */
a.main-filled-button {
  font-size: 13px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 13px 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000dff;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

}

a.main-filled-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000dff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="img-fill">
    <img src="assets/images/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="text-content">
      <h3>WELCOME TO AKSM</h3>
      <h5>Leading surveying company</h5>
      <a href="https://www.aksm.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/%CE%9CME_WEBENa-1.pdf" class="main-filled-button">EPAnEK 2014-2020</a>
      <a href="https://www.aksm.gr/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/aksm-prodiagrafes-popup.jpg" class="main-filled-button">ΠΡΟΔΙΑΓΡΑΦΕΣ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t5jomreq/).

References:

- [`align-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content).
- [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
- [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
- [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).
- [`flex-flow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow).
- [`flex-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).
- [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
- [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).
- [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
- [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
- [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
- [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
- [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
- [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
- [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).

Bibliography:

- "[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)," [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/).
- "[Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)," [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).